# Pictures don't show in IE6 after Windows XP updates

Tags: windows-xp, windows-update, internet-explorer-6

It was time to update the computer I'm using, and I ran all of the updates except for the upgrade from IE6 to IE8.  I'm using a work computer, so I'm simply not allowed to upgrade from IE6 to anything useful (some of their stuff apparently still requires IE6).  I use Chrome on the side, but I need IE for certain things.

After updating and restarting, I found that pictures in general stopped showing in IE6, except for occasional ads.  Even the Google logo does not show up.  In Chrome, however, everything works fine.  I already tried going to Tools->Internet Options->Advanced->Multimedia and checking "Show Pictures" (which was already checked), and nothing on the "why your pictures won't show!" pages online seem to help.

Any ideas?

**update:**
When I'm on the Google homepage, the bar at the bottom of the IE window says "Downloading picture http://...", and I suspect it's not the only page that says that, but there's a red X in the place of the logo, which I thought meant the browser had already given up.

**update (some time later):**
I was able to upgrade to IE7 and I'm having the same issue.  In both cases, there are certain images that show up, and certain ones that don't.  I'm wondering if images got set to `display: none !important` somewhere.  Looking into it.

**update (even later; haven't had much time to deal with this):**
Just discovered that all the missing images are apparently .png files.

Comment: **Welcome to Super User!** There is kind of a conflict; if you aren't allowed to run upgrades, then why did you ran updates? You should contact your IT section/guy for support to get this fixed again; see my answer...

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! The updates needed to be run, but the upgrade to IE8 had been hidden by a higher admin, and I was told verbally that I needed to keep IE6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three options, I doubt if the first one will work:

1. Completely [reset Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923737), also try reinstalling Internet Explorer.
2. Turn the system back to a proper state using System Restore.

   Not running every update at the same time could help to figure out which update caused this...
3. Upgrade to a newer version of Internet Explorer, perhaps the work things might still work.

Good luck, the most viable option seems to be 2...

Comment: Agh. I was hoping for an easy fix.  I upgraded to IE7 without it working, but I might have to try IE8.  I'm accepting the answer because it seems extremely reasonable that one of these will work (and I don't want to deny you your rightful rep just because I don't have time to fiddle yet).